# All routes in directed graph

Tags: prolog

I want to make a program which should give out all possible routes between two stations. The problem I have is that it doesn't give me all routes. My code so far is:

```
connection(s1,s2).
connection(s2,s3).
connection(s3,s4).
connection(s4,s5).
connection(s5,s1).
connection(s1,s4).
connection(s2,s5).

direction1(X,Y) :- connection(X,Y).
direction2(X,Y) :- connection(Y,X).

route1(X,Y,R):- route1(X,Y,[X],R).
route1(X,Y,_,[X,Y]) :- direction1(X,Y).
route1(X, Y, Visited, Route) :- direction1(X, Z), Z \= Y, \+ member(Z, Visited), route1(Z, Y, [Z|Visited], Route1), Route = [X|Route1].

route2(X,Y,R):- route2(X,Y,[X],R).
route2(X,Y,_,[X,Y]) :- direction2(X,Y).
route2(X, Y, Visited, Route) :- direction2(X, Z), Z \= Y, \+ member(Z, Visited), route2(Z, Y, [Z|Visited], Route2), Route = [X|Route2].

route(X,Y,R) :- route1(X,Y,R); route2(X,Y,R).
```

[image]
[image]
For example when I ask for "`?- route(s1,s4,R)`" it only gives me `R = [s1, s4]`, `R = [s1, s2, s3, s4]` and `R = [s1, s5, s4]`.
But there are also the routes (s1,s2,s5,s4) and (s1,s5,s2,s3,s4) and I don't know why I don't get them. How to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is enough

```
direction(X,Y) :- connection(X,Y).

direction(X,Y) :- connection(Y,X).

route(X,Y,R) :-
   route(X,Y,[X],R).

route(X,Y,_,[X,Y]) :-
   direction(X,Y).

route(X, Y, Visited, [X | Hr]) :-
  direction(X, Z),
  Z \= Y,
  \+ member(Z, Visited),
  route(Z, Y, [Z | Visited], Hr).
```

I mean: use only one `direction/2` instead the duplication of `direction1/2` and `direction2/2`. The use of the `Visited` list permit you to avoid the potential loop.

So you can unify `route1/3` and `route2/3` in a single `route/3`.

Your code fail finding `[s1, s2, s5, s4]` because from `s1` to `s5` you need `direction1/2` (so `route1/3` and `route1/4`) but from `s5` to `s4` you need `direction2/2` (but `route1/4` doesn't call `direction2/2`).

In similar way your code fail finding `[s1, s5, s2, s3, s4]` because you need `direction2/2` (so `route2/3` and `route2/4`) from `s1` to `s2` but you need `direction1/2` from `s2` to `s4`.

Comment: Thanks! You made any essential changes between the first code you posted and the one you have edited now?

Comment: @zer0kai - yes; I've only semplified a little.

Comment: @zer0kai - yes: the same.